# Hack.chat on my public IP

Tags: node.js, networking

So, I found this cool chat some days ago ;
https://github.com/AndrewBelt/hack.chat

I managed to install it and everything is working.
The server is at `127.0.0.1:6060` and the client ( running through `http-server` is at `0.0.0.0:8080`.

So I ran it and locally, it works.
So I was wondering what about making this chat public all over Internet using my public IP ?

- Go to config.js
- Change host to my public IP `xx.xxx.xx.x`

Then I tried to launch the server using `node server.js` and here the problem start !

> root@user:~/hack.chat# npm start
>   hack.chat@1.0.0 start /root/hack.chat
>   node server.js
>   Started server on 88.169.22.4:6060
>   events.js:85
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>               ^
>   Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
>       at Server._listen2 (net.js:1139:19)
>       at listen (net.js:1182:10)
>       at net.js:1280:9
>       at dns.js:85:18
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
>       at startup (node.js:129:16)
>       at node.js:814:3
>   
>   npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-22-generic
>   npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
>   npm ERR! node v0.12.7
>   npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! hack.chat@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Failed at the hack.chat@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
>   npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the hack.chat package,
>   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   npm ERR!     node server.js
>   npm ERR! You can get their info via:
>   npm ERR!     npm owner ls hack.chat
>   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>   
>   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /root/hack.chat/npm-debug.log

Here is the npm-debug.log file output ;
http://pastebin.com/a1N6NVkt

I searched what this problem could be, I saw some people sayin' that some process are launched on the same port but when I do a `fuser 6060/tcp` or `fuser 8080/tcp`, it show me that no process are currently running on these ports.

--
EDIT: With what I found on the web, this error is from the config.json file. I can't provide my remote address as server but don't know how to fix it
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know who or what made you think that you should change the host to your public IP, but that makes no sense. Your public IP only makes sense outside your network and that machine is on your network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved !
The problem was that I didn't opened the 6060 port..
I'm really stupid lol
For the future ones who got the same problem just do this :
Redirection from port 80 to port 8080
Open the port 6060
Set the http-server and the server with IP : 0.0.0.0
And everything should works.
Thanks for the ones who helped me <3

Answer (score 1):

The IP address `0.0.0.0` means that the port will be bound to accept connections from any source address. In other words, the configuration by default allows hack.chat to be used from any IP address. If [`http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) (or any other static file HTTP server) is also bound to `0.0.0.0`, then both the static files and the WebSocket connection will be available to the public.

Comment: First, thanks for the answer,
Now I understand how it works so I set up the client / server parameter with 0.0.0.0.
Server is listening at port 6060
Client is listening at port 8080
When I go on 127.0.0.1:8080 everything works as charm.

So now I wanted to open it publicly so my friends can talk to me.
I redirected the port 80 to 8080 so when they go to my public IP they'll be redirected directly to the client. It worked.
The problem here is that it seems that the client can't connect to the server when we try to connect to the chat using the public IP !

Comment: Too long so sorry for double comment ;
Here is an error I found by checking the console on chrome :
`connection to 'ws://xx.xxx.xx.x:6060/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`